# In Kubernetes, how can I scale a Deployment to zero when idle

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm running a fairly resource-intensive service on a Kubernetes cluster to support CI activities. Only a single replica is needed, but it uses a lot of resources (16 cpu), and it's only needed during work hours generally (weekdays, 8am-6pm roughly). My cluster runs in a cloud and is setup with instance autoscaling, so if this service is scaled to zero, that instance can be terminated.

The service is third-party code that cannot be modified (well, not easily). It's a fairly typical HTTP service other than that its work is fairly CPU intensive.

What options exist to automatically scale this Deployment down to zero when idle?

I'd rather not setup a schedule to scale it up/down during working hours because occasionally CI activities are performed outside of the normal hours. I'd like the scaling to be dynamic (for example, scale to zero when idle for >30 minutes, or scale to one when an incoming connection arrives).

Comment: What cloud are you using for your cluster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom solution: https://github.com/greenkeytech/zero-pod-autoscaler

Compared to Knative, it's more of a "toy" project, fairly small, and has no dependency on istio. It's been working well for my use case, though I do not recommend others use it without being willing to adopt the code as your own.

Comment: If you want to keep using the built-in HPA, check out https://github.com/machine424/kube-hpa-scale-to-zero

Answer (score 17):

Actually Kubernetes supports the scaling to zero only by means of an API call, since the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler does support scaling down to 1 replica only.

Anyway there are a few Operator which allow you to overtake that limitation by intercepting the requests coming to your pods or by inspecting some metrics.

You can take a look at  [Knative](https://knative.dev/) or [Keda](https://keda.sh/).
They enable your application to be serverless and they do so in different ways.

**Knative**, by means of Istio intercept the requests and if there's an active pod serving them, it redirects the incoming request to that one, otherwise it trigger a scaling.

By contrast, **Keda** best fits event-driven architecture, because it is able to inspect predefined metrics, such as lag, queue lenght or custom metrics (collected from Prometheus, for example) and trigger the scaling.

Both support scale to zero in case predefined conditions are met in a equally predefined window.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, Keda looks interesting.

Comment: I was specifically searching for a confirmation that "Both support scale to zero". Thanks.Edit: found a reference on that in KEDA doc https://keda.sh/docs/1.5/concepts/scaling-deployments/#overview

Comment: To make KEDA more interesting, they have recently announced a HTTP-based system for scaling to zero: https://keda.sh/blog/2021-06-24-announcing-http-add-on/

Comment: It is possible via the HPAScaleToZero feature gate, if you cannot enable it and you want to keep using the built-in HPA, check out github.com/machine424/kube-hpa-scale-to-zero

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways this can be achieved, possibly the most "native" way is using Knative with Istio. Kubernetes by default allows you to scale to zero, however you need something that can broker the scale-up events based on an "input event", essentially something that supports an event driven architecture.

You can take a look at the offcial documents here: https://knative.dev/docs/serving/configuring-autoscaling/

Answer (score 3):

The horizontal pod autoscaler currently doesn’t allow setting the minReplicas field to 0, so the autoscaler will never scale down to zero, even if the pods aren’t doing anything. Allowing the number of pods to be scaled down to zero can dramatically increase the utilization of your hardware.

When you run services that get requests only once every few hours or even days, it doesn’t make sense to have them running all the time, eating up resources that could be used by other pods.

But you still want to have those services available immediately when a client request comes in.

This is known as idling and un-idling. It allows pods that provide a certain service to be scaled down to zero. When a new request comes in, the request is blocked until the pod is brought up and then the request is finally forwarded to the pod.

Kubernetes currently doesn’t provide this feature yet, but it will eventually.

Answer (score 1):

based on documentation it does not support minReplicas=0 so far. read this thread :-https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69687. and to setup HPA properly you can use this formula to setup required pod :-

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

you can also setup HPA based on prometheus metrics follow this link:-

https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscale-with-custom-metrics-8cb13e9d475

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes version 1.16 or later, you must enable the `HPAScaleToZero` feature gate on kube-apiserver to support scaling to 0. It only supports object/external metrics.

> my PR handled the validation of zero value of minReplicas for
> object/external metrics so you can either wait for the next stable K8S
> release or setup v1.16.0-alpha.1.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69687#issuecomment-513745438